# Dropzone in Codeigniter url not used?

Tags: codeigniter, dropzone

I'm using Dropzone in Codeigniter. I can see in Chrome's Network inspector that the URL is picked up (it sends a request to the URL), but it seems that the upload function in the controller is not executed.

Whatever URL I put in the Dropzone config, the Network inspector always indicates that it returns a HTTP 200 code.

**View**

```
<div class="dropzone" id="my_dropzone"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#my_dropzone', {
  paramName: "file",
  url: '/pretty/url/upload-photos',
}
```

Note; whatever URL parameter I put here the Network inspector always indicates that it returns a HTTP 200 which is weird to me. Even if I put a non-existing URL like /asdfasdf.

With CodeIgniter I'm used to working with pretty URLs in AJAX and then mapping them to a controller in the routes config, this always works fine.

I've also tried directly putting the path to the function and controller as the URL parameter, like `url: /folder/subfolder/Edit/upload_photos`. This doesn't work as well.

**In config/routes.php**

```
$route['/pretty/url/upload-photos'] = '/folder/subfolder/edit/upload_photos'
```

**In the controller 'Edit.php' (that's located in application/folder/subfolder)**

```
public function upload_photos()  
{
  echo 'test 1';

  if(!empty($_FILES)) {

    echo 'test 2';

    var_dump($_FILES);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your Dropzone `url:` only needs to be `/edit/upload_photos`. And you don't need a `$route[]` entry.

Comment: Same result. Whatever I put as the url parameter it always gives a HTTP 200 code, but doesn't execute the upload_photos function.

Comment: Does chrome's js console complain? Maybe put a `console.log()` message in the dropzone sending or success events?  http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-sending

Comment: It turns out that the function is actually being called with the setup described in the answer (pretty URL in routes.php mapping it to the controller and function). It doesn't echo the 'test 1' string, but if I put code to upload the images they are uploaded.Any idea why 'test 1' is not being echoed but image upload code is being executed? Also, if I put a redirect there it's not executed (it's shown in the network tab but not actually executed).

Comment: I think your 'test 1' and 'test 2' are getting sent as a response back to the dropzone ajax call. You'd get a 200 because it's not really an error, per se. You could use `log_message()` to write to CI's log file and see if 'test 1' shows up there.

Comment: I'll try that. Still weird that even with non-existing URLs I would get a 200. On top of that, redirects are not working, but I guess that's because it's an AJAX call from Dropzone.

Comment: UPDATE: is it :-). I'll handle this on the client side.